# SQL Server: Update a Column, concatenate char with that column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have a table that contains a column that I need to update if the length of that value is equal to 1, the thing is that if this is true I need to get that value and concatenate a 0 before it, for example:

If the value of the column is equal to "5" I need to update that row to "05", I need to do this for all the rows that match this criteria.

I tried this:

```
UPDATE WS 
SET WS.used_brand=CONCAT('0',(Select WS.used_brand FROM WS)) WHERE LEN(WS.used_brand) = 1;
```

It doesn't work because of the inner select, how can I fix this?.

Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
UPDATE WS
    SET WS.used_brand = CONCAT('0', WS.used_brand)
    WHERE LEN(WS.used_brand) = 1;
```

Note:  Many databases support `LPAD()` or a similar function for padding values on the left.

In SQL Server, you would more likely write this as:

```
UPDATE WS
    SET WS.used_brand = '0' + WS.used_brand
    WHERE LEN(WS.used_brand) = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a nested `SELECT` statement - you can reference the column just like this:

```
UPDATE WS 
SET WS.used_brand=CONCAT('0', WS.used_brand) 
WHERE LEN(WS.used_brand) = 1;
```